# Why is ast.CallExpr not a valid ast.Expr?

Tags: go

I'm working on some Go AST code, and the compiler is choking on this line:

```
var call ast.Expr = ast.CallExpr{Fun: ast.NewIdent("foo"), Args: []ast.Expr{ast.NewIdent("api")}}
```

The error it's giving me is:

> cannot use ast.CallExpr literal (type ast.CallExpr) as type ast.Expr in assignment:
>
> ast.CallExpr does not implement ast.Expr (End method has pointer receiver)

I have no idea what this is saying; [according to the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#CallExpr), everything looks fine.  What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: You're missing a `&`.  The Pos and End methods are implemented by `*CallExpr`

Comment: @JimB Thanks!  Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pos` and `End` methods of `ast.Expr` are implemented by `*ast.CallExpr`. You need to assign a pointer to `call` with `&`.

```
var call ast.Expr = &ast.CallExpr{Fun: ast.NewIdent("foo"), Args: []ast.Expr{ast.NewIdent("api")}}
```